# В логах OpenVPN статус REVOKED у рабочих ключей

Tags: linux, openvpn

Пользователю временно был выдан удаленный доступ с помощью OpenVPN.
После выполненных функций, ключи пользователя были перемещены в папку `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/revoked`.
Впоследствии, пользователю снова нужен был доступ и данные ключи (.crt, .csr, .key) были перемещены
в `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/` и `/etc/openvpn/ccd` .

Но в логах со стороны сервера (Ubuntu) упорно выдается, что ключ отозван:

`Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 LZO compression initialized
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '360696c5'
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '13a273ba'
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]79.79.79.13:52015, sid=1f1bca19 a8c61716
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 CRL CHECK OK: /C=RU/ST=77/L=Moscow/O=COMPANY/CN=COMPANY_CA/emailAddress=it@COMPANY.ru
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=RU/ST=77/L=Moscow/O=COMPANY/CN=COMPANY_CA/emailAddress=it@COMPANY.ru
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 CRL CHECK FAILED: /C=RU/ST=77/L=Moscow/O=COMPANY/CN=vpn-mks/emailAddress=it@COMPANY.ru is REVOKED
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error: error:140890B2:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:no certificate returned
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mon Aug  1 16:30:40 2016 79.79.79.13:52015 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting`

Со стороны клиента (Windows 7) логи:

`Mon Aug 01 17:31:33 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.11 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on May 10 2016 Mon Aug 01 17:31:33 2016 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 32bit Mon Aug 01 17:31:33 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.09 Enter Management Password:
Mon Aug 01 17:31:33 2016 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340 Mon Aug 01 17:31:33 2016 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340 Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192] 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1470058294,RESOLVE,,, 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef] 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]79.1.1.1:1194 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1470058294,WAIT,,, 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1470058294,AUTH,,, 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]79.1.1.1:1194, sid=d57d0f42 29d70bb7 Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=RU, ST=77, L=Moscow, O=COMPANY, CN=COMPANY CA, emailAddress=it@COMPANY.ru 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER 
Mon Aug 01 17:31:34 2016 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=RU, ST=77, L=Moscow, O=COMPANY, CN=server, emailAddress=it@COMPANY.ru 
Mon Aug 01 17:32:34 2016 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity) 
Mon Aug 01 17:32:34 2016 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed 
Mon Aug 01 17:32:34 2016 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting 
Mon Aug 01 17:32:34 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1470058354,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,
Mon Aug 01 17:32:34 2016 Restart pause, 2 second(s)`

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/400887/292034

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо. Заработало.

Comment: 1d0, напишите, пожалуйста, ответ. чтобы информация была полезна ещё кому-нибудь. или удалите вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Конечно, уже написал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделаю How-to на русском все-таки.

Вообще, такая практика, как я понял, не совсем правильная.
99.9% нужно перевыпускать ключи.
Но если с перевыпуском ключей, какие-то проблемы, то можно сделать следующим образом.

1) В папке с сертификатами (например: `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/`) должен находиться файл **index.txt**, в котором хранится список сертификатов. На основе данного файла генерирутеся CRL (certificate revocation list).

2) В данном файле, нужно найти строчку с требуемым сертификатом, который следует восстановить.

В первом столбце у отозванных сертификатов стоит статус - **R**, у валидных - **V**.
Соответсвенно, меняем у отозванного сертификта данный статус на **V** и удаляем третий столбец вида **160510070838Z** (это дата отзыва сертификата).

3) Теперь нужно перегенерировать CRL на основе нашего нового файла index.txt.

Скрипт для регенарации CRL созданный из скрипта revoke-full

```
#!/bin/bash

#regenerate CRL,

CRL="crl.pem"
RT="revoke-test.pem"

if [ "$KEY_DIR" ]; then
    cd "$KEY_DIR"
    rm -f "$RT"

    # set defaults
    export KEY_CN=""
    export KEY_OU=""
    export KEY_NAME=""

    # generate a new CRL -- try to be compatible with
    # intermediate PKIs
    $OPENSSL ca -gencrl -out "$CRL" -config "$KEY_CONFIG"
    if [ -e export-ca.crt ]; then
        cat export-ca.crt "$CRL" >"$RT"
    else
        cat ca.crt "$CRL" >"$RT"
    fi

else
    echo 'Please source the vars script first (i.e. "source ./vars")'
    echo 'Make sure you have edited it to reflect your configuration.'
fi
```

Сохраняем данный скрипт (например, ./crl-regen).

4) Загружаем переменные

```
root@server:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa# . ./vars
```

5) Выполняем данный скрипт

```
root@server:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa#sh crl-regen
```

Готово!